# TextInputEdit Text Counter about text length

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am not sure on which is the "better" way to handle max lengths on an edit text.

Is it better to display a counter displaying the max characters allowed in a text field, but let the user type in any amount and display an error once the user submits the form

Or

Display the counter with the max chars allow and limit them to that amount so if the user goes over the amount, it stops entering in more characters?

I know either way is "fine" I would like to know what is the best way to handle this scenario from a users perspective.

Comment: second one any day...why to let him type extra chars and then tell him to delete all those...such a waste of time for user..also give a ui that will catch his eyes and indicate that chars are over otherwise he might no realise that he is still typing after limit is reached

Comment: Even though the dialog that he is typing in, has the limit counter like 0/30?

Comment: yes when you start typing you don't start counting chars ..so they won't realise it

Comment: thanks @KunalParikh

Comment: any time buddy @x10sion

Comment: @x10sion Try to type a comment here you will see how So handle it isn't that good ;)

Answer (score 3):

From user's perspective, I would hate if a dialog box pops up and tells me that whatever you typed has exceeded the length limit. That would be less intuitive than the 2nd option where you limit the user to the type anymore than the specified length.

Comment: Even though the dialog that he is typing in, has the limit counter like 0/30?

Comment: Yes. The user would hate to delete all the characters. Instead restricting him or her to the length would save him time.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as we are using Android and current UI/UX specs are here https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-character-counter and to use that feature you need design support lib. The code to make it work is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="300">
      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/comment_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/comment_hint"
                    android:lines="4"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: this is exactly how i do it but i was wondering if i should let the user carry on typing it instead of limiting them

Comment: The counter should enter "error mode" and you should disable any post buttons, showing Snackbar or Toast msg

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to display counter with max limit on of Edittext. While user typing you should tell user remaining text. Once it reach on the limit then you show counter in negative manner.

While submitting displaying error that "Text exceeding limit. It will be omitted" and give option to Proceed and Edit.

[image]

You can use a **TextWatcher** to display limit

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
private int textLimit=60;


private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //This sets remaining text 
           if(s.length()>textLimit){
                  mTextView.setText("-"+(s.length() - textLimit));
           } else {
                  mTextView.setText("-"+(textLimit - s.length()));
           }
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
};
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Comment: this is what i am currently doing, but i also thought about limiting the user to the max chars so that they cannot type any more

Comment: Limiting user to write its against business logic. You should not do that.

Comment: you mean setting a limit at all on an edit text as in server side, or limiting them from typing in the edit text is against business logic?

Comment: I am talking exactly like this. http://prntscr.com/eezdek . This is standardized manner.

Comment: thats an interesting way of erroring on an edit text. thanks for that